# I don't know how to convert this query to eloquent or Fluent query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I use Laravel v5.1.4. I searched over net but I couldn't find any solution. I tried many ways but I couldn't figure out how to convert this query to Eloquent or Fluent Query Builder. Here is working Query with select.

```
DB::select("SELECT t1.id,t1.date1,t1.date2, t2.name as pick, t3.name as dest
        FROM reservations AS t1
        LEFT JOIN prices AS t2 ON t1.pick = t2.id
        LEFT JOIN prices AS t3 ON t1.dest = t3.id
        ORDER BY t2.name ASC
        ");
```

I want to use Eloquent or Fluent Functions such as pagination. I will be grateful if you help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. I hope it will be helpful to people who has same problem :)

```
DB::table('reservations')->join('prices as t1','reservations.pick',"=","t1.id")
                        ->join('prices as t2','reservations.dest',"=","t2.id")
                        ->select('reservations.id','t1.name as result1','t2.name as result2')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Just so that I know, would pagination work with this type of solution? Or are there issues like there are with groupBy?

Comment: you can use all Query Builder functions. No issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. it's the idea how you will convert

```
DB::table('users')
            ->LeftJoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
            ->LeftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'roles.name as role');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this is not solution. You use two different tables "role_user" table and "roles" table. if you use same tables you cannot get two different name result . if you check my query I join same table two times. And I need to get two different name result from prices table. You can check my solution